# How do I know the arguments to create a key binding shortcut to run a custom package in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I realise that to create a Key Binding in Sublime Text 3 I will have something like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+u"], "command": "upper_case" },
```

However for a custom package I need to add arguments and the name of package:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+12"], "command": "hex_viewer", "args":{"cmd": "setb"} }
```

Only I have no idea what those are or how to find them. I'm guessing that the package name.
The line above is incorrect as it generates a error (when viewed in the console).

Whilst I realise a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910586/add-shortcut-key-for-multiple-plugins-in-sublime-text-3) exists, refers to Sublime Text 2 this refers to version 3

Comment: That binding is generating an error because keyboards don't have a `12` key; replacing that with a valid key (for example maybe you meant `f12`?) will stop the error. You still need to know what command (not package name) to bind to though. The above shows you how to do that. The question you linked to regards creating multiple key bindings for the same key, which it doesn't seem like you're trying to do.

Comment: @OdatNurd Well spotted. Looks like I didn't need the arguments after all, as it kicked out another error However, `{ "keys": ["ctrl+f12"], "command": "hex_viewer" }` worked fine! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out the desired command from your favorite package, I would suggest using `sublime.log_commands(True)` & `sublime.log_input(True)` in the sublime console input. Once that's done, perform the action (based on your favorite package) for which you want to bind the key to. Once that's done, look in the console. You should see something similar to

```
key evt: control+k
key evt: control+b
command: toggle_side_bar
```

(This was logged because I toggled the sidebar).

With this, you will understand what command is behind that action and then you can bind it to your favorite key binding.

This method however, is not guaranteed to show arguments that the command provided by the said package can take. For that, either you can look into the default key bindings of the said package or read through the documentation for that package (if any).

Hopefully, this helps a bit.